# wildfly not use persistence-unit config

Tags: jpa, wildfly, datasource

i use this configuration in persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="xxxxx" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.behpanel.demo.model.Sessions</class>
        <class>com.behpanel.demo.model.Invoices</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qqqqq"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="****"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******"/>
            <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" 
            value="com.behpanel.demo.config.NamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
            <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

when run application in intellij idea and deploy on local wildfly server. wildfly dont use this persistence-unit and use default data source.
and crud actions not persist on mysql db and that actions persist on default datasource that is h2 database.

Comment: Where did you place the persistence.xml? And why don't you use a data source that is defined in standalone.xml?

Comment: Try changing your `transaction-type` to `JTA`. `RESOURCE_LOCAL` is for an SE environment meaning you'd be responsible for controlling the entity manager.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it was in resource->META-INF

Comment: and what are you deploying? A WAR or an EAR?

Comment: In case of war, is it located in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml ?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli war